# How to make this design in flutter , chat box

Tags: flutter, dart, design-patterns, flutter-getx

[image]

I need to make this design in flutter , this a sample chat box in chat screen

I was make it but this slidible is not work with me

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that share code as images instead of code blocks usually indicate you haven't read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and people often skip right over them. So share your code as indicated. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter_slidable` package:

[flutter_slidable](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable)

or use `Dismissible` widget. [What is dismissible?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEMgjrfuc58)